# Submit multiple inputs using formData()

Tags: javascript, axios, form-data

I want to use AJAX request and able to submit multiple input, so I use FormData for this.

I have no idea how to append multiple input with same name ("name[]"). I tried this method but somehow it is not working. I don't know what is the right way to do it, I've been trying many ways but it just won't work. Thanks for advance!

```
<input type="text" name="test[]">

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test[0]',1);
formData.append('test[1]',2);
formData.append('test[2]',3);

axios({
    method:'post',
    url:'url',
    data:formData,
    config:{headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}}
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);      
});
```

Comment: Please explain how it is _"not working"_. What form of data is your server-side code expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server-side code is actually expecting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request body and not `multipart/form-data`, try something like this

```js
axios.post('url', new URLSearchParams([
  ['test[]', 1],
  ['test[]', 2],
  ['test[]', 3]
])).then(response => console.log(response))
```

When [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is serialised to a string format, it comes out like

```
"test%5B%5D=1&test%5B%5D=2&test%5B%5D=3"
```

and Axios will automatically set the `Content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`